# Process Future[Try[Option]] in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a method that returns Future[Try[Option[Int]]]. I want to extract value of Int for further computation. Any idea how to process it??

Comment: try to understand why you have a Future[Try[Option[Int]]]. If you check both Future a Try have methods to go to Option, and you can try to map your result that come from a methods composition in a single Future

Comment: I agree with @FabioFumarola. It's very unfortunate to have to deal to that kind of type.

Comment: The correct answer largely depends on how do you want to handle the error cases for the Future, the Try and the None. Please add more details on this.

Comment: A future is basically a delayed try, so you can perhaps ```.flatMap(Future.fromTry(_))``` to flatten it to a ```Future[Option[Int]]``` first? Then you only have one layer of Success and Failure to deal with.

Comment: @tilaert You can also do: `future.transform(_.flatten)`

Answer (score 2):

```
future.map(_.map(_.map(i => doSomethingWith(i))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want use [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/) you can do fun (for certain definitions of fun) things like:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import cats.Functor
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.implicits._

val x = Future { Try { Some(1) } } // your type

Functor[Future].compose[Try].compose[Option].map(x)(_ + 2)
```

This is suggested ONLY if you're already familiar with cats or scalaz.
Otherwise, you're great to go with any of the other valid answers here (I especially like the map-map-map one).

Answer (score 1):

Just `map` the future and use match case to handle the different cases:

```
val result: Future[Try[Option[Int]]] = ???
result.map {
  case Success(Some(r)) =>
    println(s"Success. Result: $r")
    //Further computation here

  case Success(None) => //Success with None
  case Failure(ex) => //Failed Try
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Converting `Future[Try[Option[Int]]]` to `Future[Int]`**

One hacky way is to convert the unfavourable results into failed future and flatMapping over.

Convert try failures to Future failures preserving the information that exception originated from Try and convert None to NoneFound exception.

```
val f: Future[Try[Option[Int]]] = ???

case class TryException(ex: Throwable) extends Exception(ex.getMessage)
case object NoneFound extends Exception("None found")

val result: Future[Int] = f.flatMap {
  case Success(Some(value)) => Future.successful(value)
  case Success(None) => Future.failed(NoneFound)
  case Failure(th) => Future.failed(TryException(th))
}

result.map { extractedValue =>
  processTheExtractedValue(extractedValue)
}.recover {
  case NoneFound => "None case"
  case TryException(th) => "try failures"
  case th => "future failures"
}
```

Now in every case you know from where the exception has originated. In case of NoneFound exception you know Future and Try are successful but option is none. This way information is not lost and nested structure is flattened to `Future[Int]`.

Now result type would be `Future[Int]`. Just use map, flatMap, recover and recoverWith to compose further actions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really concerned about extraction see this, else go through the answer by @pamu to see how you actually use your Future.

Suppose your Future value is `result`.

`Await.ready(result, 10.seconds).value.get.map { i => i.get}.get`

Obviously this wont get through your failure and None cases and would throw exceptions and Await is not recommended.

So if you want to handle Failure and None case ->

```
val extractedValue = Await.ready(f, 10.seconds).value.get match {
 case Success(i) => i match {
  case Some(value) => value
  case None => println("Handling None here")
}
 case Failure(i) => println("Handling Failure here")
}
```